# codeigniter encrypted string not able to decrypt after logout

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, session-cookies

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$encoded_string = $this->encrypt->encode('my_string_to_secure');

$this->load->library('encrypt');
$original_string_after_decode = $this->encrypt->decode('encoded_string ');
```

this code encodes and than decodes the given string properly

but when i set this encoded_string into cookie and after logout when i try to decrypt this encoded_string i am not able to decrypt this

i am using encryption key set in config file.

Comment: may be your cookie gets destroyed after logout. Check if cookie exists before you try to decode it

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your encode string which is store in variable `$encoded_string` try

```
$original_string_after_decode = $this->encrypt->decode($encoded_string);
```

For more:- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: sir i have done that,and i had edited code here to make it more readable

Comment: use session instead cookie and don't destroy all session only destroy user session